# Error: origin_mismatch using subdomains with Google Sign In button

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-signin

I've followed [Adding the HTML sign-in button to your page](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/add-button) instructions, and made it work in my development environment. At production I need to support subdomains, but I can't make it work. I've changed `data-cookiepolicy` from `single_host_origin` to `https://mydomain.com` [as API reference says](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/reference#determining_a_value_for_cookie_policy), so this way it should support login from `https://mysubdomain.mydomain.com`. I've also added `https://mydomain.com` to Javascript origins at Google Developer Console. Nevertheless, when I click Login button, after authentication step, a **400** error is displayed, with **Error: origin_mismatch** message. It works if I add the url with the subdomain to the Javascript origin list, but that's not what I need, since I don't know them in advance (and might be tons).

What might I missing? Thanks! :_(

Comment: I've never used this. +1 for bringing it to my attention. So, will it work if you just use **http** instead of **https**, like this? `data-cookiepolicy="http://example.com"`

Comment: Nop, my problem is not the *schema* but the *subdomain*. The schema must be *https*. It works if I add `https://mysubdomain.mydomain.com` to the Javascript origin list, which is something I think shouldn't have to (I can't add my subdomains there).

Comment: I submitted an issue for this at, so please help and vote it up https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11796

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like you must add every subdomain (!). [See this question, with a workaround hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24166191/google-api-authorized-javascript-origins) and [this other Google Groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/oauth2-dev/sj5jeksUV4M).

Comment: Vote for the problem to be actually fixed here. https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11796