# Add video to user's Favorite/Like playlist on YouTube

Tags: javascript, php, video, youtube, youtube-api

The aim is to create a Favorite/Like button using the YouTube API. When a user clicks the button, the video is saved into the user's Favorite/Like playlist.

Just like how it works when you implement a Facebook like button on your own site.

This is essentially a follow up question to the fantastic solution posted by [Bertrand Martel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42561941/1649673) on my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42513339/1185126) where we aimed to add a video to the Watch Later playlist.

The working code for this particular function is:

```
<!-- button 1 -->
<button type="submit" data-youtube-video-id="EH3gqI2NAiE" value="Watch Later" class="ma_youtube_watch_later" name="send">
  <div class="ma_youtube_watch_later_text">Watch Later</div>
</button>

<!-- button 2 -->
<button type="submit" data-youtube-video-id="0EMmKIIF-zE" value="Watch Later" class="ma_youtube_watch_later" name="send">
  <div class="ma_youtube_watch_later_text">Watch Later</div>
</button>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  // By Bertrand Martel: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42561941/1649673
  var OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = '28993181493-c9o6hdll3di0ssvebfd4atf13edqfu9g.apps.googleusercontent.com';
  var OAUTH2_SCOPES = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube'
  ];
  var init = false;
  var youtube_video_id = '';

  var button = null;

  googleApiClientReady = function() {
    gapi.auth.init(function() {
      window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
    });
  }

  function checkAuth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize({
      client_id: OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
      scope: OAUTH2_SCOPES,
      immediate: true
    }, handleAuthResult);
  }
  // Handle the result of a gapi.auth.authorize() call.
  function handleAuthResult(authResult) {

    jQuery('.ma_youtube_watch_later').off('click');
    jQuery('.ma_youtube_watch_later').click(function(e) {

      button = this;

      var youtube_video_id = jQuery(this).attr("data-youtube-video-id");

      // Add a video ID specified in the form to the playlist.
      function addVideoToPlaylist() {
        //addToPlaylist(jQuery('#video-id').val());
        addToPlaylist(youtube_video_id);
      }

      if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        addVideoToPlaylist();
      } else {
        init = true;
        gapi.auth.authorize({
          client_id: OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
          scope: OAUTH2_SCOPES,
          immediate: false
        }, handleAuthResult);
      }
      return false;
    });

    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
      // Authorization was successful. Hide authorization prompts and show
      // content that should be visible after authorization succeeds.
      jQuery('.pre-auth').hide();
      jQuery('.post-auth').show();
      loadAPIClientInterfaces();

      jQuery('#add_to_wl').click(function(e) {

        button = this;

        addVideoToPlaylist(self);
      });
    }
  }

  function loadAPIClientInterfaces() {
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
      if (init) {
        init = false;
        addVideoToPlaylist();
      }
    });
  }

  // Add a video to a playlist. The "startPos" and "endPos" values let you
  // start and stop the video at specific times when the video is played as
  // part of the playlist. However, these values are not set in this example.
  function addToPlaylist(id, startPos, endPos) {
    var details = {
      videoId: id,
      kind: 'youtube#video'
    }
    if (startPos != undefined) {
      details['startAt'] = startPos;
    }
    if (endPos != undefined) {
      details['endAt'] = endPos;
    }
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.insert({
      part: 'snippet',
      resource: {
        snippet: {
          playlistId: "WL",
          resourceId: details
        }
      }
    });

    request.execute(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      if (!response.code) {
        //jQuery('#status').html('<pre>Succesfully added the video : ' + JSON.stringify(response.result) + '</pre>');

        // change button text
        $(button).text('Video added');

      } else if (response.code == 409) {

        //jQuery('#status').html('<p>Conflict : this video is already on your Watch Later playlist</p>');

        // change button text
        $(button).text('Already added');

      } else if (response.code == 404) {
        //jQuery('#status').html('<p>Not Found : this video hasnt been found</p>');

        // change button text
        $(button).text('Video not found');

      } else {
        //jQuery('#status').html('<p>Error : code ' + response.code + '</p>');

        // change button text
        $(button).text('Error: Try again');

      }
    });
  }

</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady"></script>
```

And we have a number of [PHP code samples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php) on the API docs. We also have some documentation on [adding a video to playlist](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_playlists#Adding_a_video_to_a_playlist).

How can this be achieved using either PHP or/and javascript?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can find Like & Favorite playlist ID with channel list endpoint with the following parameters (check [this sample request](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list?part=contentDetails&mine=true)) :

```
{
    mine: true,
    part: 'contentDetails'
}
```

You will get the list of playlists in `relatedPlaylists` including `likes`, `favorites`, `uploads`, `watch later` and `watch history`.

```
{
    "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
    "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/S1x68O9aSpvmndklrnSwKw_yYdE\"",
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 1,
        "resultsPerPage": 1
    },
    "items": [{
        "kind": "youtube#channel",
        "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/ura_vsrPt5tCZkjjGbH3ihN3Bq4\"",
        "id": "UCnQt5EmYRfX1uVYtwPNj7Dg",
        "contentDetails": {
            "relatedPlaylists": {
                "likes": "LLnQt5EmYRfX1uVYtwPNj7Dg",
                "favorites": "FLnQt5EmYRfX1uVYtwPNj7Dg",
                "uploads": "UUnQt5EmYRfX1uVYtwPNj7Dg",
                "watchHistory": "HL",
                "watchLater": "WL"
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

For WatchLater & WatchHistory, the playlistId is the same for all users (respectively WL & HL)

You can call channel list endpoint in Javascript with `gapi.client.youtube.channels.list` the same way as you've called the playlist insert API.

Then with the playlistId you can insert your video to another playlist than Watch Later.

In the following code, you will find 3 buttons to add different videos to `Watch Later` playlist, `Like` playlist & `Favorite` playlist

---

## Javascript

[Here](https://bertrandmartel.github.io/youtube-watch-later/multi-playlist.html) is a live demo with the [source code](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/youtube-watch-later) (as below)

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/bmartel/3nsevqkx/4/) is a fiddle. Replace your client id and add as Authorized JavaScript origins in developer console : https://fiddle.jshell.net

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Add to multiple playlists</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="submit" data-youtube-video-id="EH3gqI2NAiE" data-type="WL" value="Add to Watch Later playlist" class="yt_add_to_playlist" />
    <input type="submit" data-youtube-video-id="0EMmKIIF-z" data-type="likes" value="Add to Like playlist" class="yt_add_to_playlist" />
    <input type="submit" data-youtube-video-id="T4ZE2KtoFzs" data-type="favorites" value="Add to Favorite playlist" class="yt_add_to_playlist" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = '28993181493-c9o6hdll3di0ssvebfd4atf13edqfu9g.apps.googleusercontent.com';
    var OAUTH2_SCOPES = [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube'
    ];
    var init = false;
    var button = null;

    googleApiClientReady = function() {
        gapi.auth.init(function() {
            window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
        });
    }

    function checkAuth() {
        gapi.auth.authorize({
            client_id: OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
            scope: OAUTH2_SCOPES,
            immediate: true
        }, handleAuthResult);
    }

    // Handle the result of a gapi.auth.authorize() call.
    function handleAuthResult(authResult) {

        jQuery('.yt_add_to_playlist').off('click');
        jQuery('.yt_add_to_playlist').click(function(e) {

            button = this;

            if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
                addToPlaylist($(this).attr("data-youtube-video-id"), $(this).attr("data-type"));
            } else {
                init = true;
                gapi.auth.authorize({
                    client_id: OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
                    scope: OAUTH2_SCOPES,
                    immediate: false
                }, handleAuthResult);
            }
            return false;
        });

        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
            // Authorization was successful. Hide authorization prompts and show
            // content that should be visible after authorization succeeds.
            jQuery('.pre-auth').hide();
            jQuery('.post-auth').show();
            loadAPIClientInterfaces();

            jQuery('#add_to_wl').click(function(e) {
                button = this;
                addToPlaylist($(this).attr("data-youtube-video-id"), $(this).attr("data-type"));
            });
        }
    }

    function loadAPIClientInterfaces() {
        gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
            if (init) {
                init = false;
                addToPlaylist($(button).attr("data-youtube-video-id"), $(button).attr("data-type"));
            }
        });
    }

    function addToPlaylist(videoId, playlistType) {

        console.log("add to playlist type : " + playlistType);

        if (playlistType != "WL" && playlistType != "HL") {

            var request = gapi.client.youtube.channels.list({
                mine: true,
                part: 'contentDetails'
            });

            request.execute(function(response) {
                var playlistId = response.result.items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists[playlistType];

                if (typeof playlistId != 'undefined') {
                    console.log("found playlist id : " + playlistId);
                    insertToPlaylist(videoId, playlistId);
                } else {
                    console.log("playlist not found");
                }

            });

        } else {
            insertToPlaylist(videoId, playlistType);
        }
    }

    function insertToPlaylist(videoId, playlistId) {

        var details = {
            videoId: videoId,
            kind: 'youtube#video'
        };
        var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.insert({
            part: 'snippet',
            resource: {
                snippet: {
                    playlistId: playlistId,
                    resourceId: details
                }
            }
        });

        request.execute(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            if (!response.code) {
                $(button).val('Video added');
            } else if (response.code == 409) {
                $(button).val('Already added');
            } else if (response.code == 404) {
                $(button).val('Video not found');
            } else {
                $(button).val('Error: Try again');
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Replace `OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID` with your own client ID

In the API response, the status code is checked in case the video is not found (`404`). The `409` status code is returned if the video is already in the playlist but only for watch later playlist (adding an existing video to like/favorite playlist will not changed anything though)

---

## PHP

The same as before, based on [google-api php sample](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/php/playlist_updates.php) :

- install composer : see [instructions](https://getcomposer.org/download/)
- install google-api client :

  ```
  composer require google/apiclient:~2.0
  ```

The php script [`multi-playlist.php`](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/youtube-watch-later/blob/master/multi-playlist.php) :

```
<?php
/**
 * Library Requirements
 *
 * 1. Install composer (https://getcomposer.org)
 * 2. On the command line, change to this directory (api-samples/php)
 * 3. Require the google/apiclient library
 *    $ composer require google/apiclient:~2.0
 */
if (!file_exists(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php')) {
  throw new \Exception('please run "composer require google/apiclient:~2.0" in "' . __DIR__ .'"');
}
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
session_start();

$response = "";

/*
 * You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from the
 * {{ Google Cloud Console }} <{{ https://cloud.google.com/console }}>
 * For more information about using OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs, please see:
 * <https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication>
 * Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
 */
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');

$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
    FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);

$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);
// Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
// Check if an auth token exists for the required scopes
$tokenSessionKey = 'token-' . $client->prepareScopes();
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
    die('The session state did not match.');
  }
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}
if (isset($_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey]);
}
// Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  try {

    $videoId = "";

    if (isset($_GET['video'])){
      $videoId = $_GET['video'];
    }
    else if(isset($_SESSION['video'])){
      $videoId = $_SESSION['video'];
    }

    if (isset($_GET['action'])){
      $action = $_GET['action'];
    }
    else if(isset($_SESSION['action'])){
      $action = $_SESSION['action'];
    }

    if(isset($videoId) && isset($action) && !isset($_GET['state'])) {

      file_put_contents('php://stderr', print_r("adding video to watch later playlist " . $videoId . "\n", TRUE));

      if ($action == "Add to Watch Later playlist") {
        $playlistId = "WL";
      }
      else {
          $listResponse = $youtube->channels->listChannels("contentDetails", array(
              'mine' => true
          ));

          if (!empty($listResponse)) {
            if ($action == "Add to Like playlist"){
              $playlistId = $listResponse['items'][0]['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['likes'];
            }
            else if ($action == "Add to Favorite playlist"){
              $playlistId = $listResponse['items'][0]['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['favorites'];
            }
          }
      }

      if (isset($playlistId)){

        // 5. Add a video to the playlist. First, define the resource being added
        // to the playlist by setting its video ID and kind.
        $resourceId = new Google_Service_YouTube_ResourceId();
        $resourceId->setVideoId($videoId);
        $resourceId->setKind('youtube#video');

        // Then define a snippet for the playlist item. Set the playlist item's
        // title if you want to display a different value than the title of the
        // video being added. Add the resource ID and the playlist ID retrieved
        // in step 4 to the snippet as well.
        $playlistItemSnippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_PlaylistItemSnippet();
        $playlistItemSnippet->setTitle('First video in the test playlist');
        $playlistItemSnippet->setPlaylistId($playlistId);
        $playlistItemSnippet->setResourceId($resourceId);
        // Finally, create a playlistItem resource and add the snippet to the
        // resource, then call the playlistItems.insert method to add the playlist
        // item.
        $playlistItem = new Google_Service_YouTube_PlaylistItem();
        $playlistItem->setSnippet($playlistItemSnippet);

        $playlistItemResponse = $youtube->playlistItems->insert(
            'snippet,contentDetails', $playlistItem, array());

        $response = json_encode($playlistItem);
      }
      else{
        $response = "no playlist selected";
      }

      $_SESSION['video'] = "";
      $_SESSION["action"] = "";
  }
  else{
    file_put_contents('php://stderr', print_r("no video was specified", TRUE));
  }

  } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    $response = htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage());
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $response = htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage());
  }
  $_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {

  if(isset($_GET['video'])){

    $_SESSION["video"] = $_GET['video'];
    $_SESSION["action"] = $_GET['action'];

    // If the user hasn't authorized the app, initiate the OAuth flow
    $state = mt_rand();
    $client->setState($state);
    $_SESSION['state'] = $state;
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . $authUrl);
  }
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Add to playlists</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form id="form" action="multi-playlist.php"">
            <input type="hidden"  name="video" value="EH3gqI2NAiE">
            <input name="action" type="submit" value="Add to Watch Later playlist" />
            <input name="action" type="submit" value="Add to Like playlist" />
            <input name="action" type="submit" value="Add to Favorite playlist" />
        </form>
        <div>
          <?php echo $response ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

For this PHP version, note that in addition to the video id in the current session `$_SESSION["video"]`, the target action is also stored in `$_SESSION["action"]` to be able to determine which playlist to use. Playlists are retrieved with channel list endpoint with `$youtube->channels->listChannels`.

---

Note that it can take some time for the video to appear in the playlists (sometimes a few seconds)

Comment: Praise you for taking the time to piece this together, thank you. I am going to test it this week. I have one question. Is it possible to add video to multiple playlists simultaneously? Example, in the type data attribute value, we add an array like `data-type="WL, likes"` and video is added to those playlists. Not sure if YouTube has some form of blocking of this.

Comment: I don't think so, the [playlist insert endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert) doesn't implement bulk insert (an object is needed for the `playlistId` field, when using an array it only takes into account the first item). You will need to make 2 successive playlist insert calls

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I have been inactivate the past few days and didn't manage to reward this bounty on time. I have reached out to the community via [this meta thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348322/missed-rewarding-a-bounty-on-time) and will hopefully get you the remaining points! Also, I should note that I have not tested this code on my local environment (will do so later this week) but judging by your previous answer, it will certainly function accordingly.

Comment: Looks like it won't work. Another option is to bounty 100 points on a random answer of yours and give you points this way. Do you have any favorite answer of yours which hasn't received enough attention? ;-)

Comment: Don't worry :) keep your reputation in case you need it later. Let me know if you have some issue with this code

Comment: @BertrandMartel You have a bug in your code. The `else if (response.code == 409)` and others only works for `WL` playlists. It doesn't work for `favorites` and `likes` playlists. So even if the video is added in the users favorites playlist, they will see `$(button).val('Video added');`. You can easily see this issue in your own [demo](https://bertrandmartel.github.io/youtube-watch-later/multi-playlist.html), just click on the like or favorite one twice... Do you have a fix for this issue? Beside this issue, this answer is a monster. Congratulations on putting it together. +1000 if I could!

Comment: I've already mentioned that : `The 409 status code is returned if the video is already in the playlist but only for watch later playlist (adding an existing video to like/favorite playlist will not changed anything though)`. If you want to check if the video is not already in the playlist, you have to make a call to `playlistItem.list`, see an example [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list?part=snippet&playlistId=FLnQt5EmYRfX1uVYtwPNj7Dg&videoId=_Ps8U_lhjPg&_h=12&). If the request return 404, the video is not in the playlist