# How do I avoid manually updating my Google OAuth client ID for every new Cognito user pool?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I want my web application to be multitenanted with one AWS Cognito user pool per tenant, as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/bp_user-pool-based-multi-tenancy.html

I also want my application to support federated sign-in with Google. So a user should be able to visit the Cognito hosted UI and choose "Continue with Google".

According to AWS's [Add social sign-in to a user pool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-configuring-federation-with-social-idp.html) instructions, I need to configure my Google "OAuth client ID" with the domain of a single Cognito user pool. But: each of my tenants will have its own Cognito user pool domain. According to [Authorized Javascript Origins wildcard alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69538854/authorized-javascript-origins-wildcard-alternative), it's impossible to set a wildcard domain like `https://*.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com` as an authorized JavaScript origin on an OAuth client ID. And according to [how to create a oauth client id for gcp programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51549109/how-to-create-a-oauth-client-id-for-gcp-programmatically/62163950) it is impossible to programmatically create/update these OAuth client IDs - you can create an IAP OAuth client programmatically, but I don't think IAP OAuth clients are what I need here.

So: do I have to manually update my OAuth client ID with a new authorised JavaScript origin and authorised redirect URI every time a new tenant is created? Is there any alternative?